# URL Rewriting without domain

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two .htaccess files. 1 in the base directory (public_html) and another in public_html/application

**public_html/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule . - [L]
    RewriteRule ^$   application/    [L]
    RewriteRule (.+) application/$1  [L]
</IfModule>
```

**public_html/application/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>                                                                                  
    RewriteEngine on                                                                                  
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f                                                               
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d                                                               
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]                                                        
</IfModule>
```

Now, this works perfectly when it is located at http://domain.com, however it does not when I am working out of a development folder, and accessing it through http://domain.com/~user/ - The page ends up 404.

My assumption is that it must be the tilde username url that is throwing it off. Any thoughts?

Comment: It may be rewriting to http://developmentdomain.com/ instead of http://developmentdomain.com/~user/

Comment: That's what I'm thinking. I'm just not sure how to let it know of the `/~user`.

Comment: Ha, that's why I'm here. I've exhausted the search results. Maybe I dont know how to search it in the correct context.

Comment: Try to rewrite it more specifically. Like including "/" to the starting